# What disadvatages are there to using Dojo, extJS, and Jquery at same time while developing?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, extjs, dojo

I noticed Jquery widgets (for example the [accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion))  appear visually nicer than those of Dojo and ExtJS.
I noticed people consider Dojo and ExtJS good for larger web apps.
I also noticed Dojo has nice plots and ExtJS seems to have nice data grids.

So I was wondering if I should just use all 3.

I want to know about the disadvantages for using using all 3 libraries for a web app project?

Comment: Other than finding another developer that knows all three that well?

Comment: If you don't like the visual part, perhaps you should think about themeing one framework or another. ExtJS is themable, although people say it's quite difficult. Ext 4 (to be released soon) is suppposed to be easier in this area.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, I'd have to agree with meo's statement that 3 libraries is likely overkill, especially if you're only judging by first impressions.  Potential maintenance woes aside - think about how much code you'd be asking all your users to download and execute; it can add up.

Here's a couple other things to keep in mind.

Both jQuery UI and Dojo widgets can be custom skinned.  While I'm not experienced with jQuery UI, I can say that Dojo's widget templates tend to be pretty well-written in terms of having sufficient classes to enable flexible style customization.  If you've got enough resources to be considering developing against 3 libraries at once, perhaps consider spending resources on customizing designs on top of one instead.

Also, just in case you haven't - have you seen Claro (new in Dojo 1.5)?  I dare say it's quite a step above the other themes.  http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit/themes/themeTester.html

Regarding ExtJS, I don't know what kind of project you're working on, but if it's a commercial project, keep in mind you need to pay for licenses, starting at around $600 a pop.

Dojo also has [a grid component or three](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/), and I'm pretty sure there is a plugin or two for jQuery as well (such as [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)).

And yes, out of the three you've mentioned, jQuery will likely give you the least OOTB towards serious rich internet applications.  I've already linked Rebecca Murphey's post (which itself links to a follow-up) about this to death, but I'll do it again as it continues to be relevant:

http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/on-jquery-large-applications

Comment: In the same vein, I can vouch for jQuery UI's widgets, as far as ease of "skinability" goes.

Comment: @Franqueiro Thanks for the great answer...thanks for the overview...and very useful points in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

It would be the total overkill. It would just make your app slow. Basically the 3 Libs do the same things with a little different syntax. Use what corresponds you. The appearance is not a argument i think, since you can style anything with some CSS magic. All 3 are pretty awesome but my personal preference goes to jQuery (best documentation and large community).